# Why ubuntu 20.04 is not running startup file of QT same as the it execute through manually from terminal?

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu-20.04

I m using Linux ubuntu 20.04. I added my executable file of QT at home/desktop. When i run this QT executable file manually through command line it works fine. But the issue arise when i run this executable as my startup file through Startup Application.

I am  not able to understand why the same code run differently when i run through as a startup file or manually by terminal. The difference between the output is that some icons are overlapping by other and some are vanished in the executable which run automatically by startup Application at the start of PC.

I think this issue arises cause of some settings for startup file. Please help me in this and tell what i sthe issue.

Comment: Maybe the current working directory matters?

Comment: can u explain it bro??

Comment: Maybe the current [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) matters?